# Windows7 IE9 NTLM Response to Challenge not being sent by client

Tags: windows-7, client-side, ntlm

I have an old laptop running WinXPpro and both IE8 and CoolNovo which can download an applet just fine from our Win2008 Server R2 SP1 x64 IIS 7.5.7600.16385.  I have a new laptop (same hardware) with a x64 Windows7 and IE9 and CoolNovo which can't download the applet (.jar file) from the same server.  I can download this .jar file directly as a url and I can download and run the applet over the internet from the .jar product provider on both laptops just fine.  So it has something to do with my new laptop.  If we add anonymous authentication to the web server, our app works on both too.

Using fiddler, I can see the NTLM authentication conversation on both laptops.  On the old one, it works just fine:
 A 401 with the WWW-Authenticat Header is present: Negotiate and one for NTLM
 Then a 401 (challenge - NTLM type 2), 
 Followed by a 200 with the client sending the NTLM type 3 header

On the new laptop, I get the first two 401s, but no 200.  It simply tries again with the 401s 2 more times.

Any ideas why the new Windows7 laptop would not be sending a 200 NTLM type3 response to the server or what the issue here might be?

Old Laptop: jre6: 1.6.0_30 checked as the user java runtime env.  No System java runtime versions checked.
new Laptop: jre6: 1.6.0_31 checked as the user AND system java runtime env.

TVMIA.

Comment: Are you trying to get integrated authentication?

Comment: Well, I have a couple of potential ideas. Did you add the site to the Local Intranet zone? Alternatively, does it work if you turn off "Integrated Windows Authentication" under Internet Options, Advanced, Security. (Note that this just turns off Kerberos, not NTLM.)

Comment: The site is added to the Local Intranet zone, and I've tried both enabling and disabling the "Integrated Windows Authentication" options with no change in behavior.

Comment: I'm stumped then, sorry. One last thing you could do is to look for audit failures in the security log.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue and after looking in server security log a have found two strange record just after each unsuccessful logon:
1. 4624 - successful logon. and just after that:
2. 4634 - successful logoff

Very strange... I've googled for these event codes and found this thread:
[SCCM reporting not working on W2K8 R2 64-bit](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/configmgrsetup/thread/04fa019b-a383-417d-a912-0a5979e1c8e9)

And the solution to this problem is:

```
1. Open the IIS Manager and go to your site
2. Double click Authentication under IIS
3. Click on Windows Authentication and then choose "Providers..." under Actions
4. Add NTLM if it isn't there and move it to the top.
5. Click OK
```

It worked for me!